# Updating Value in same instance using invokeLater

Tags: java, invokelater

My program is supposed to search for a computer name and update the computer name value in the same instance of the GUI that it was searched in. If I launch the application and search for the computer name and hit search, it won't appear in the same instance. If I hit run again, the computer name I just searched for appears in the label in the new instance of the GUI.

So basically at the moment I have to launch a new instance of the GUI to see the updated computer name. Any help is appreciated. I've been stuck on this for a long time now.

Relevant Code:

`try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new` FileReader("resultofbatch.txt")))
    {

```
    final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("CN=([^,]+).*");
    try {
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] tokens = PATTERN.split(","); //This will return you a array, containing the string array splitted by what you write inside it.
            //should be in your case the split, since they are seperated by ","
           // System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            CN = sCurrentLine.split("CN=",-1)[1].split(",",-1)[0];

            System.out.println(CN);
           testLabel.setText(CN);
        }


    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();


}
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MISControlPanel window = new MISControlPanel();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                    //testLabel.setText(CN);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

You can view the full class here: http://pastebin.com/8hH1TMD3

Comment: Why is pretty much everything static?

Comment: That's from just tinkering with the code trying to get it to work. I just removed the static global variables.